# Custom MongoDB spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I want to implement custom repo with Spring data mongodb.
Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepositoryCustom repo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(this.repo.customMethod());
    }
}
```

My custom repository CustomerRepositoryCustom.java

```
public interface CustomerRepositoryCustom {
    List<Customer> customMethod();
}
```

Custom implementation CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl.java

```
  public class CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl implements CustomerRepositoryCustom {
        @Autowired
        private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

        @Override
        public List<Customer> customMethod() {
            return this.mongoTemplate.findAll(Customer.class);
        }

    }
```

Code Structure

```
-Application.java
  dal
    model...
    repository
     -CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl.java
     -CustomerRepositoryCustom.java
```

When I try to build it, i get an error:

```
    **Description**:
Field repo in socketApp.Application required a bean of type 'socketApp.dal.repository.CustomerRepositoryCustom' that could not be found.


**Action**:
Consider defining a bean of type 'socketApp.dal.repository.CustomerRepositoryCustom' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally downvoted instead of upvoted and cannot change the vote unless you make an edit to the question.

Comment: Its ok if it helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make Spring *aware* of your repository. For a Spring Boot application this is typically done by adding this annotation to your application ...

```
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.package.path.to.repository")
```

.... thereby telling Spring Boot where to look for Mongo repositories and then let your interface extend `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository`.

For example:

```
public interface CustomerRepositoryCustom extends MongoRepository {
    List<Customer> customMethod();
}
```

Alternatively, you could annotate your `CustomCustomerRepositoryImpl` with `@Repository` and ensure that it is in a package which is scanned by Spring Boot.

Comment: @Repository works fine. However 
@EnableMongoRepositories("socketApp.dal.repository") is not working
Path to file: C:\Users\{user}\Desktop\spring-mongodb\src\main\java\socketApp\dal\repository